# How to render user input from a form to another page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building an expense manager website however I'm not sure how to render the expenses and income. I've already saved the data to localStorage and generated ID's. I have an edit page where the user fills out the expense form to create an expense and when they click submit I want the expense details to be rendered to the home page.
How do I render user input from the edit page to the home page when the submit button is clicked using JavaScript?

I'm receiving errors saying: "i" is read-only.

```
// What I've changed (JS)
const displayExpenses = (targetElem) => {
    let html = `<div class="amnt-expense">`;

    for (const i = 0; i < this.expenses.length; i++) {
        html += `<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" required></div>
        <div class="text-expense"> <textarea type="text" id="description" name="description"></textarea>`
    }

    html += `</div>`
    targetElem.innerHTML = html;
    return displayExpenses(targetElem)
}
// I've put the form's id in 'expenses'
const account = {
    name: '',
    expenses: ['#expense-form'],
    income: [],
```

```
// Home Page (HTML)

    <div class="header"> <h1>Expense Manager</h1><p id="p-head">Keep track and stay debt free!</p></div>
   <div class="center">
      <select>
        <option value="byPrice">Least Expensive</option>
        <option value="alphabetical">Alphabetically</option>
        <option value="byEdited">Last Edited</option>
      </select>
   <p>Item1</p>
   <p>Item2</p>
   <button id="income">Add Income</button>
   <button onclick="location.href" id="add-expense">Add Expense</button>
    </div>
```

```
// Edit expense form
<form id="expense-form">
       <div class="amnt-expense"><input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" required></div>
       <div class="text-expense"> <textarea type="text" id="description" name="description"></textarea></div>
        
   <button onclick="location.href" id="submit-expense">Submit</button>
   <button id="remove">Remove Expense</button>
</form>
```

```
const account = {
    name: '...',
    expenses: [],
    income: [],
   
    
    addExpense: function (description, amount) {
      this.expenses.push({
          description: description,
          amount: amount
      })
    },
getAccountSummary: function () {
        let totalExpenses = 0
        let totalIncome = 0
        let accountBalance = 0

       this.expenses.forEach(function (expense) {
           totalExpenses = totalExpenses + expense.amount
       })
account.addExpense('Rent', 850)
account.addExpense('Food Shopping', 60)
console.log(account.getAccountSummary())


// Read existing expenses from localStorage
const getSavedExpenses = () => {
    const expensesJSON = localStorage.getItem('expenses')

    try {
    return expensesJSON ? JSON.parse(expensesJSON) : []
} catch (e) {
    return []
}
}
const expenses = getSavedExpenses()

// Save expenses to localStorage
const saveExpenses = (expenses) => {
localStorage.setItem('expenses', JSON.stringify(expenses))
}
//Listen for new expense to be created
$('#add-expense').on('click', function() {
location.href = '/expense.html'
})
$('#submit-expense').on('click', function() {
saveExpenses(expenses)
location.href = '/index.html'
})
$('#add-expense').on('click', function () {
    const id = uuidv4()
    expenses.push({
        id: id,
        title: '',
        body: ''
    })
saveExpenses(expenses)
    location.href = `/expense.html#${id}`
    console.log(id)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over your accounts.expenses and use Javascript to populate the form with the values....if the data is saved in localStorage then you need to pull it and store it into the accounts.

It's not entirely clear how you need it presented but perhaps this will help you...you'll likely need to tweak your key names in your expense object... also the targetElem param would be the element itself your inserting the data into.

```
displayExpenses: (targetElem, paramExpenses) => {
    let html = `<div>`;

    for (var i = 0; i < paramExpenses.length; i++) {
        html += `<label>Description: 
                    <textarea type="text" id="description" name="description">${paramExpenses[i].description}</textarea>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div> 
                <label>Amount: <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value="${paramExpenses[i].amount}" required></label>`
    }

    html += `</div>`;

    targetElem.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Please explain in more detail and present more relevant code if this solution hasn't helped you.

Response to comments:
Pass in the parsed local storage into the second param...you should likely add an if statement to handle the logic if getSavedExpenses() returns an empty array.

```
displayExpenses(firstParam, getSavedExpenses());
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You've helped me get a better understanding of what I need to do although I'm still a bit confused. I tried typing that into my html however I didn't know what else to do. My data is stored in localStorage but I'm not sure what JavaScript to use to take it and store it in the accounts. I've edited my question providing some more code. @Michael Paccione

Comment: Okay so in this example whats going on is your are on an edit page with a form? You enter the values into the form and submit and it saves? The question you are asking is how to display what is saved on the other page? If so where is the code for the html of that part?

Comment: After you parse your JSON form local storage store it into memory in your account object and then use a displayExpenses function to render it...

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes that's exactly what I'm asking. I've added the HTML for that part as well as the code that I changed (the displayExpenses function etc) to my question. I know that I'm still doing it wrong but I don't know what to change. @Michael Paccione

Comment: @RJDdev in regards to your 'i' is read only... change it from a "const" to a "let" in the loop.

Comment: Also why are you returning the HTML in the display expenses function when it already sets the innerHTML of the target element?

Comment: I've changed the 'const' and deleted the return statement. I now have zero errors! Although I only have my ID saved in localStorage, not the expense description or amount and nothing is rendering. @Michael Paccione

Comment: Okay, I'm editing my initial answer to take in an extra param of the expenses since you are pulling them from local storage and not working from local memory.

Comment: I don't know what element i'm inserting the data into for the targetParam. Also, should I write the if statement in my displayExpenses function? Would I pass expensesJSON or expenses as the second param? @Michael Paccione

Comment: @RJDdev the targetElem is the selector of the element you want to display the expenses in. As far as the second param you would be passing in an array of parsedJSON. If you don't parse it then it will be a string instead of an array.

Comment: This seems vulnerable to an injection attack. If a user put some clever stuff into the description, they could run any script they wanted on this site. If you are using code like this, be careful, it is always best to sanitize data from the customer before rendering it.